# in laravel When run Logout route twice consecutively , i get csrf token mismatch error

Tags: php, laravel

Suppose the user has opened two pages. In one of them, touches the logout button. Then on the other page, again, touch the logout button.

Which with error:

```
(1/1) TokenMismatchException

In VerifyCsrfToken.php (line 68)
At VerifyCsrfToken-> handle (object (Request), object (Closure)) in Pipeline.php (line 148) ......
```

. Do you have any solution?

Comment: Why would you logout twice?

Comment: @CarlosAfonso 
Suppose the user has forgotten.

Comment: Supposing the user had already logged out your pages should not show the option for signing out again, if it did that would be an error of your system

Comment: @CarlosAfonso If the user has two pages from the site open in different tabs then they could have this issue.

Comment: @CarlosAfonso But the user has already opened two pages.And has not reloaded.

Comment: This is probably not an issue with the logout but instead with an timeout, does this also happen if you open 2 consecutive tabs and immediately close them afterwards?

Comment: @milo526 yes!. dont matter time. Immediately after logout on the first page, the second page comes with an error.

Comment: Well I see. In that case, it seems you've edited your `VerifyCsrfToken` middleware class. Have you?

Comment: @FarshidRezaei Your question seems to need the same as this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45362158/5704410

Comment: @OmisakinOluwatobi thank for comment .but i think, its not safe and standard. i found a solution that handle mismatch errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in **App\Exceptions\Handler.php** Return the user to the form with a new valid **CSRF** token, so the page will refreshed and logout button will not exist.

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{ 
   if($exception instanceof TokenMismatchException)
   { 
      return redirect()
               ->back()
               ->with('your msg');
   }
   return parent::render($request, $exception); 
}
```

this looking like, page was **refreshed**.

> Don't Replace **POST** with **Get**. It will not **Safe** And **Standard**.

Comment: It will be nice if you can explain why 1. **it is not safe** 2. **it is not standard** so that we all can learn and do it right. @Farshid Rezaei

Comment: @omisakin tell me please ,  with replace it,  so why should i handle the errors?  why laravel recommended handel the errors?

Comment: You can explain the point I asked so I can understand and also others that see the post can understand why it is needed. Your comment has not given me an explanation. But don't worry if you can't explain. Good you found the answer that suits you.