# how to manage a special error with special message in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, error-handling, laravel-5.4

I'm using laravel 5.4. and I need handle some error.
imagine user logged in and opened two windows (his profile). When user click on logout in a window, we have still logout button in another window, and by clicking on that, laravel will show csrf_token error page.

My logout in not ajax and its with submitting a form to `/logout`
how can I handle this error with special message or redirect to home without error from logout controller? (not all of `csrf_token` errors, just from that controller).

logout form :

i will submit this form by clicking on logout button using jquery:

```
<form id="logout-form" action="/logout" method="POST" style="display: none;">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" :value="token">
</form>
```

And the logout method in controller :

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $this->guard()->logout();
    $request->session()->flush();
    $request->session()->regenerate();
    return redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: **I am also involved with this issue.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in **App\Exceptions\Handler.php**
Return the user to the form with a new valid **CSRF** token, so the page will refreshed and logout button will not exist.

```
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{ 
   if($exception instanceof TokenMismatchException)
   { 
      return redirect()
               ->back()
               ->with('your msg');
   }
   return parent::render($request, $exception); 
}
```

this looking like, page was **refreshed**.

> Don't Replace POST with Get. It will not Safe And Standard.

Comment: I used to handle this kind of problems with redirects but this answer gives "the right way"

Answer (score 1):

One way is use `GET` for your logout. In fact use a simple `<a href="/logout">logout</a>` should be sufficient. So you change your route to use get and you can wave bye to the form.

> Although, there might be different opinions about the METHOD to use but truthfully, this is sufficient.

**Update**

> Isn't any way to manage errors just like what i said?

In my opinion, this is the best I would do for now. Otherwise to show special message when someone tries the logout route even though they are logged out, I will just do the following:

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    if (!auth()->check()) {
        return redirect('/')->with('login_error', 'You are already logged out please login again'); // message can be retrieved in session()
    }
    $this->guard()->logout();
    $request->session()->flush();
    $request->session()->regenerate();
    return redirect('/');
}
```

I will still not use post, since I am not creating any resource.

I hope this helps.

Comment: There could be way to do that, but thats the best I can think of for now. Maybe you should simply change your form method to GET, then change the method in your route as well to GET, remove the token field from the form, then you don't need to use the `<a href...` I suggested

Comment: The advantage is that, you don't have to worry about it showing any error, and if you want to customize your logout message in this case then its easy.  So that in your controller before anything, check `if(!auth()->check()){ do something since you are already logged out }` else just logout.

Comment: Did you change to GET?

Comment: oh yes . with get its working . why laravel used the post?? is post method more secure in this issue ???

Comment: Well, Post is more secure in this sense because it requires that you have to be logged in, and have ('csrf_token') before you can run that route, so that you can be sure the person accessing that route is the logged in user and not another person. But, in the case of logging out I don't think its really a problem, especially in handling this situation.

Comment: fine . the main way for handling errors is just app/exceptions/handler.php ???
with  this just i can handle all of csrf errors (from any where)

Comment: You can give it a try. I have never tried to handle it in handler.php before. But I don't think you need to go that length for this simple issue.

Comment: you are welcome. But don't worry its more about sharing with one another that is most important. Glad you found a solution.