# Laravel: user logs out after session has expired

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.5 and the regular provided authentication.

**Situation**:
The user leaves his computer for 2 hours (the default session timeout) and before leaving the office, he clicks on Logout.

**Problem**:
The user gets the following error:

> The page has expired due to inactivity.
>   Please refresh and try again.

Refreshing the page has no effect. The same message is displayed again.

With Laravel 5.4, I had the following error:

> TokenMismatchException in VerifyCsrfToken.php (line 68)

The link for logout is in the layout `app.blade.php` and hasn't been changed:

```
<li>
    <a href="{{ route('logout') }}"
       onclick="event.preventDefault();
                document.getElementById('logout-form').submit();">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-off"></span>
        Logout
    </a>

    <form id="logout-form" action="{{ route('logout') }}" method="POST" style="display: none;">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
    </form>
</li>
```

**Question**
How can I avoid the csrf validation when user clicks on logout?

Comment: create middleware and check session value if it's not available to move the login page.

Answer (score -1):

I've just added an exception in `App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php`

```
/**
 * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
 *
 * @var array
 */
 protected $except = [
    'logout'
 ];
```

Ajay Deepak Kumar and Omisakin Oluwatobi are right. This makes the website vulnerable.

Comment: but this makes it vulnerable

Comment: Adding this url to except is not good since you are making a post request. It would mean almost the same thing as using `GET logout` instead but if you don't care about the security concern, then its up to you

Comment: You can refer to this answer for inspiration https://stackoverflow.com/a/45375780/5704410 that is handle the exception thrown so it could for example go to the login page.

Comment: @ Omisakin Oluwatobi, in L5.5, there is no exception thrown so the solution in https://stackoverflow.com/a/45375780/5704410, doesn't work here. Cannot beleive that Laravel didn't think of this.

Comment: what about just deleting the session cookie client side on "logout" click?

Comment: I will be I interested in finding an answer to this question. God willing ill be able to attempt this today and try to give my findings